How to Design a JSON Schema for Mapping Survey Data from a CSV File with Complex Question Types?
I’m working with a large dataset containing survey responses stored in a CSV file with over 100 columns. I want to map this data to a JSON schema for better structure and downstream processing. However, I’m unsure about the best practices for designing the schema, particularly considering the variety of question types in the survey.
I cannot share the exact questions, but here is an overview of the formats I need to handle:

Simple MCQ Questions:

Example: "What is your preferred device?"

Possible answers: "Smartphone," "Tablet," "Laptop"
In the CSV, the answer is stored in one column.




MCQ Questions with Custom Answers:

Example: "What is your favorite fruit?"

Possible answers: "Apple," "Banana," "Other (please specify)."
If the user selects "Other," they can input a custom answer in a text box, which is stored in a separate column.




Multiple T/F Select Questions:

Example: "Which of the following features do you use on your smartphone?"

Possible answers:

Feature A: True/False
Feature B: True/False
Feature C: True/False


Each feature is stored in its own column. Sometimes, respondents can add a custom feature, which is stored in a separate column.




Nested Questions (Conditional Logic):

Example:

Q1: "Do you use any smartphone applications for XXX?"
If the answer is "Yes," a follow-up question appears: "What applications for XXX do you use?"
In the CSV, conditional follow-up questions are stored in separate columns that may or may not contain data, depending on the response to the primary question.





Challenges I'm Facing:
I’ve never worked on designing JSON schemas for this type of data before, and I’m finding it difficult to decide on a structure.
My Questions:

Are there any best practices or general guidelines for designing JSON schemas for survey data, especially with nested or complex question formats?
Are there tools (preferably Python-based) that could simplify or speed up the process of mapping CSV data to JSON while accounting for the various question types described above?

Any advice, examples, or pointers to relevant libraries or tools would be greatly appreciated!

Is it compulsory to use a json? In any case, you can start by using Pandas to combined related columns to only one column per question. For example, for your 3rd point, the 4 columns could be transformed to 1 column with something like [True, False, True, None].
